# AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior onTimer not called on page load

Tags: wicket

AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior onTimer not called on page load ,but if i refresh the page then it is called.
I have an class which extends panel and i override onConfigure() method.Below is the code sniffet.

```
public ClockPanel(String id)
{
    super(id);

    hkplSettings = config.load(GeneralHkplSettings.class);
    System.out.println(" ####### construcotor #####  "+hkplSettings.isDisplayCurrentDateTime());
    final Label clockLabel = new Label("clockLabel", new ResourceModel("admin.hkpl.current.time"));
    clock = new Clock("clock", propertyManager.getGeneralAdminSettings().getDisplayTimestampFormat());
    add(clockLabel);
    clock.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    add(clock);
}

@Override
public void onConfigure()
{
    super.onConfigure();

    if (hkplSettings.isDisplayCurrentDateTime())
    {
        System.out.println(" ####### in ifffff #####  "+hkplSettings.isDisplayCurrentDateTime());
        add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1))
        {
        @Override
        protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget)
        {
        System.out.println(" ****** in timer *******  "+hkplSettings.isDisplayCurrentDateTime());
        ajaxRequestTarget.add(clock);
        }

        });
        setVisibilityAllowed(true);
    }
    else
      {
        System.out.println(" ####### in else #####  "+hkplSettings.isDisplayCurrentDateTime());
        setVisibilityAllowed(false);
      }
}
```

When i deploy this app then following SOP's print

# construcotor #####

# in iffff #####

When i refresh the page then following SOP's print

# in iffff #####

********* in timer ***** and this line continue to print as expected.

### Heading

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't work for you, it seems similar to WorldClockPage from wicket-examples. Try moving your code from #onConfigure() to #onInitialize().

Comment: Thanks Siamak !!! I just tried this as well but couldn't work..Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious; is there any reason you have added AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior inside onConfigure and not at the panel level? onConfigure is called per every request.

I tried as following and seems working:

```
public class TestPanel extends Panel {
    private String clock;
    private Boolean flag = Boolean.FALSE;


    public TestPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        if (clock == null) {
            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            clock = df.format(today);
        }



        Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(form);

        final Label clockLabel = new Label("clockLbl", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "clock"));
        clockLabel.setMarkupId("clockID");
        clockLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        form.add(clockLabel);

        add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(2)) {
            @Override
            protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                clock = df.format(today);
                System.out.println(" ****** in timer *******  " + clock);
                clockLabel.setDefaultModelObject(clock);
                ajaxRequestTarget.add(clockLabel);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getClock() {
        return clock;
    }

    public void setClock(String clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        flag = Boolean.TRUE;
        System.out.println(" Inside on Configure..." + clock);
        if (flag) {
            setVisibilityAllowed(true);
        } else {
            setVisibilityAllowed(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The page having the panel shows timer updated every two seconds. The System.out.println shows as below as well:

```
Inside on Configure...08/06/2015 09:53:47
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:53:50
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:53:52
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:53:54
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:53:56
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:53:58
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:54:00
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:54:02
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:54:04
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:54:06
 ****** in timer *******  08/06/2015 09:54:08
```

Comment: Thanks Mihir..Let me try this.

Comment: Thanks Mihir!!! Now its working..But i couldn't understand what was the problem in my implementation..

Comment: You are welcome !!  In your implementation, have you tried setting debug points in constructor and onConfigure methods and check the sequence of execution when loading/refreshing page?

Answer (score 0):

That works in a new project:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onConfigure() {
      super.onConfigure();
      add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onTimer(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("timer");
        }
     });
   }
}
```